# Configure ConnectionFilter for a Named Connection

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Given the following OrmLite configuration from the documentation, what is the best way to configure the ConnectionFilter for each of the the named connections?

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    "Data Source=host;Initial Catalog=RobotsMaster;Integrated Security=SSPI",  //Connection String
    SqlServerDialect.Provider);

dbFactory.Run(db => db.CreateTable<MasterRecord>(overwrite:false));

NoOfShards.Times(i => {
    var namedShard = "robots-shard" + i;
    dbFactory.RegisterConnection(namedShard, 
        "~/App_Data/{0}.sqlite".Fmt(shardId).MapAbsolutePath(),                //Connection String
        SqliteDialect.Provider);

    dbFactory.OpenDbConnection(namedShard).Run(db => db.CreateTable<Robot>(overwrite:false));
});
```

Currently, I am using this instead of RegisterConnection.

```
    OrmLiteConnectionFactory.NamedConnections[namedShard] = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("~/App_Data/{0}.sqlite".Fmt(shardId).MapAbsolutePath(), true, SqliteDialect.Provider, true) {
        ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
    };
```

Could we change RegisterConnection to something like

```
    public void RegisterConnection(string connectionKey, string connectionString, IOrmLiteDialectProvider dialectProvider, bool autoDisposeConnection = true)
    {
        RegisterConnection(connectionKey, new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, autoDisposeConnection, dialectProvider, autoDisposeConnection));
    }

    public void RegisterConnection(string connectionKey, OrmLiteConnectionFactory ormLiteConnectionFactory)
    {
        NamedConnections[connectionKey] = ormLiteConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submitted a patch to ServiceStack.OrmLite. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/pull/212

Comment: and t'was well-received :)

Comment: @mythz sometimes I have a hard time deciding if I should post here or on github issues :)

Comment: If you're not sure if it's a real issue best to post here, otherwise if you verified it's a real issue post on GitHub issues with a reproducible failing test.